# Does anyone know a safe and reliable grammar add-on for Scrivener?

Tags: scrivener

I was finally able to change from US English spelling to Canadian spelling, but my biggest problem is with grammar. I have tried to enable a grammar tool, but can't find one I trust. It would be wonderful if the darn program included a grammar tool of its own. Heck, even Word does that.

Comment: you guys are tough... anybody home? ;)

Comment: While Writers is a worldwide site, a lot of users are from the US where we've just had a four-day holiday weekend.  Activity's been down from that, sorry.

Comment: Apparently none of us use Scrivener either... I don't know of any such add-ons. I recommend you check in at the Scrivener forums; they're more likely to have help for you: https://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=22

Comment: Also, I wouldn't go looking for grammar add-ons per-say.  If you look through some of the questions, people have been asking about grammar software and usually the software was given with the advice that you should still proof read/edit find someone who will.  Grammar software are reliable to a certain point but the other issue is they may change something that was purposely done with poor grammar.

Comment: @ggiaquin: I find astounding how many viedos are out there showing how to use whichever grammar add-on and which clearly show people blindly following advise. These add-ons are incredibly useful to catch typos and to point out **potential** grammar problems. But the user must *always* go through each problem and...

Comment: (oops, pressed enter by mistake)... and analyse each potential problem. More often than not, it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I returned to Word. I am used to it and it at least asks me about spelling. It does have some basic grammar. Now, I need to figure out moving my word doc to Scrivener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ProWriting Aid](https://prowritingaid.com/en/App/Desktop) works with Scrivener. I've used the grammar software mostly on MS Word and like it a lot. I have yet to try it on Scrivener because, at the moment, my Scrivener projects are not in English.